# Reading A Variable As Both A Number And String of Words

Tags: performance, freepascal

I am trying to get `Dep_Code` to read as a string after choosing the options given (1, 2 or 3). I first had it set to integer in my first program (I think) and was able to get it to read out the options given as words (Accounts `ACC` or the others). However, it was accidentally deleted. I've tried various ways to get it even setting `Dep_Code` as a string but its not working and I keep getting a variety of errors. Btw, I'm not familiar with programming so I'm aware that the following code is quite incorrect... but I hope you all can help. Thank you!

```
REPEAT
      writeln ('Please enter the Department Code:- ');
      writeln;
      writeln ('1. Accounts (ACC)');
      writeln ('2. Human Resources (HR)');
      writeln ('3. Operations (OP)');
      writeln;
      readln (Dep_Code);

      IF Dep_Code = 1 THEN
         Dep_Code := ('Accounts (ACC)')

      ELSE IF Dep_Code = 2 THEN
              Dep_Code := ('Human Resources(HR)')

           ELSE IF Dep_Code = 3 THEN
                   Dep_Code := ('Operations (OP)');
UNTIL ((Dep_Code >= 1) AND (Dep_Code <= 3));
```

Comment: "Btw, I'm not familiar with programming". Then I suggest you get a good textbook about Pascal and follow the examples given there before you start doing something like this. Recommendation: [Essential Pascal](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/) by Marco Cantù. Or his similar book about Object Pascal.

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. Pascal is a strictly typed language, and something cannot be an Integer **and** a string at the same time, and variables cannot change type either:

```
 IF Dep_Code = 1 THEN
     Dep_Code := ('Accounts (ACC)')
```

But **you don't need a string at all**. Keep it an integer. The functions that handle the various depts can write or define such strings, if necessary. Your logic for the menu does not need a string variable.

Do something like:

```pascal
procedure HandleAccounts(var Error: Boolean);
begin
  ...
end;

// Skipped the other functions to keep this answer short ...

var
  Dep_Code: Integer;
  AllFine: Boolean;

// Skip the rest of the necessary code ...  

  repeat

    // Skipped the Writelns to keep this answer short ...

    Readln(Dep_Code);
    Error := False;

    case Dep_Code of
      1: HandleAccounts(Error);
      2: HandleHumanResources(Error);
      3: HandleOperations(Error);
    else
      Error := True;
    end;   

  until not Error;
```

*Above, I skipped some of the code. You can fill in the blanks, I guess.*

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @LuQinxin: Don't just thank me, but [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it really helped.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't know I was supposed to tick the mark

Comment: Well, you found out after all. Thanks.